# How to get average of column values in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Lets say I have this column

```
star
----
1    
3    
3    
1    
2    
5    
3
```

It has seven rows and there are integer values! I want to have it added and divided by the rows there are.

How do I do it in laravel. I can do it in plain php but I want to learn it in laravel.

Comment: If you are having these values in database then `AVG()` would help. In php `array_sum($array)/count($array)`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this :

```
$avgStar = Model::avg('star');
```

" Model " will replace with your model name

Answer (score 13):

If you want to do it with the query builder you can use aggregate methods like `avg`:

```
$avg_stars = DB::table('your_table')
                ->avg('star');
```

[Laravel 5 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#aggregates) about aggregates.

Answer (score 4):

If you have more columns you can use the native function of the database manager using `DB::raw`

```
$products = DB::table('products')
                 ->select('id','name',DB::raw('round(AVG(quantity),0) as quantity'))
                 ->groupBy('id','name')
                 ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
$avgStar = yourModel::avg('columnName');

// in this case
$avgStar = yourModel::avg('star');
```

Try this if you need to add multiple conditions - with model:

```
$avgStar = YourModel::Where(
  [
    ['star', '>', 1],
    ['star', '<>', 0]
    .....
  ])->pluck('star')->avg();
```

With database:

```
 $avgStar = DB::table('table_name')->Where(
  [
    ['star', '>', 1],
    ['star', '<>', 0]
    .....
  ])->pluck('star')->avg();
```

Answer (score -1):

`Table::Where('column', $case)->pluck('column')->avg()`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This will first load all `column` in memory, then loop through it and calculate avg, this is expensive, instead, let MySQL do it like mentioned above.

Answer (score -3):

> // let's say the Model name is Review and Table name is reviews, you have a
>   'star' column on it

```
$value = Reviews::all();
$value->avg('star');

return view('page.name')->withValue($value);
```

> // it will calculate an average of star column