# Perform average in array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, average

I'm trying to calculate an average in my table. The column name is `term1_result` and the average is in the array since my table has many students and subjects. I group them by `student_id`, but I always end up getting a zero value. I'm using the [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel) framework.

**Code**

```
$scores = Grades::with('student', 'subject')->groupBy('student_id')->get();

foreach($scores as $score) {
    foreach($score as $key => $value) {
        $sum_arr[] = $value['term1_result'];
    }
    $avg = array_sum($sum_arr) / count($sum_arr);
    $avgarr[] = $avg;
}

dd($avgarr);
```

**Result**

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => 0
  1 => 0
  2 => 0
  3 => 0
  4 => 0
  5 => 0
]
```

Comment: You can get the average with the query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529067/how-to-get-average-of-column-values-in-laravel

Comment: Can you please add here what you get in $scores ?

Comment: can you share Grades, student and subject table structure

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your SQL content!

Have you dump your scores to see result?

You must sum over each items in each groups.

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887708/laravel-eloquent-sum-with-groupby) to learn more

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$scores = Grades::with('student','subject')->groupBy('student_id')->avg('term1_result');
```