# Mysql how to get the total of feedbacks?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I'm making a feedback stars rating system for products using Laravel with MySQL,
how can I make MySQL count all rates and get the average of 5 stars?

So by laravel I am going to just use `get()` to get the average.

```
//sample data:

id | rate
1     4
2     2

//expected output:

3
```

Comment: Put some sample data with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer more precisely, the structure of the table should be known.
You can group the desired lines and then divide by the number. something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(rate)/COUNT(1) FROM table GROUP BY 1
```

or with  AVG function

```
SELECT AVG(rate) AS avgRate
FROM table
GROUP BY xyz;
```

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

```
DB::table('your_table')
                ->avg('star');
```

Comment: where can I store this line in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @wailhayaly this isn't what phpmyadmin is for.

Comment: I do not understand the question. The sql statement can be executed directly in the SQL window.

Comment: you can test this stament in phpMyAdmin, but you must integrate this in your php-code.

Comment: @Strawberry I guess I can use `avg` function with laravel for retrieving the average, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
$rateAvg = Model::avg('rate');
```

Check this links for more

[How to get average of column values in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529067/how-to-get-average-of-column-values-in-laravel)

[Aggregates in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results)