# How Can i fetch all data with average rating in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

I want to display all the products with their average rating. In this case, I Have two tables like **Product Table** and **Product Rating Table**

For example:

My Products table

```
ProductID  | ProductName
-------------------------
1          | ABC Product
2          | XYZ Product
3          | LMN Product
```

My Rating Table

```
   ID   | ProductID  | Value
    -------------------------
    1   | 1          | 4
    2   | 1          | 5
    3   | 2          | 3
```

I need to get output like this,

```
 [
    {
     "ProductID": 1,
     "ProductName": ABC Product,
     "AverageRating": 4.5,
    },

    {
     "ProductID": 2,
     "ProductName": XYZ Product,
     "AverageRating": 3.0,    
    },  

   {
     "ProductID": 3,
     "ProductName": LMN Product,  
     "AverageRating": 0,
    }

 ]
```

How can I get this output in laravel? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get average of column values in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529067/how-to-get-average-of-column-values-in-laravel)

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel Framework 7.16.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = DB::table('products_table')
->select('products_table.ProductId', 
         'products_table.ProductName', 
         \DB::raw('AVG(ratings_table.value) as AverageRating')
->leftJoin('ratings_table', 'ratings_table.ProductId', 'products_table.ProductId')
->groupBy('ratings_table.ProductId')->get();

return $data->toArray();
```

I haven't run this query, but this might give you an idea for your questions.